# How can i take encrypted data in a byte array and put that into an HTTP request in a binary format using C#

Tags: c#, .net, http, encryption

I want to take encrypted data in a byte array and put that into an HTTP request in a binary format. So far I have this code in C#

```
byte[] encryptedBytes = var encryptor.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt);

HttpRequestMessage newHttpMessage =  new HttpRequestMessage();

newHttpMessage.Content = encryptedBytes;
```

I have been provided with an example in Javascript, I need to achieve the same but using C#

```
                $.post({ 
                        url: "xyz",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        headers: {
                            
                            "Ing-Plain-Content-Length": jsonData.length
                        },
                        data: new Uint8Array(encrypted),
                        processData: false,
                        xhr: function () {
                            return xhrOverride;
                        },
                        dataType: "binary",
```

Comment: Send binary as a Mime attachment or convert binary to 64 bytes string (Convert.ToBase64String()).  A Mime attachment starts with a new line containing two dashes.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)

Comment: How would this be implemented with C#? I have tried to use the ByteArrayContent type but it doesn't seem to work. message.Content = new ByteArrayContent(sevenItems);

Comment: You need to add it to the existing Content.  The MIME is part of the body